# Using jQuery to switch between tabs using opacity for emphasis

Tags: jquery, tabs, click, toggle, opacity

The Problem:

I'm creating a gallery page for my personal portfolio site. I need it to have multiple links across the top, for different categories of my art. Upon landing on the site, the "all" option will be selected, and all of the thumbnails of my art will be showing and at full opacity. When a link is clicked only the thumbnails belonging in the category corresponding to the link will remain at 100% opacity, while the others will dim to 50%.

I have code that I think is close to correct, but still does nothing. Below is the code I'm working with.

The (Abbreviated) HTML:

```
<ul id="filterOptions">
<li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="ty">Typography</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pr">Print</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="ourHolder">
<li data-type="ty"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a></li>
<li data-type="il"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a></li>
<li data-type="pr"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a></li>
```

The CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');

  var $data = $holder.clone();

    $('#filterOptions li a').click(
    function(e) {
        // reset the active class on all the buttons
        $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');

        // assign the class of the clicked filter option
        // element to our $filterType variable
        var $filterType = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

        if ($filterType == 'all') {
            // assign all li items to the $filteredData var when
            // the 'All' filter option is clicked
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
            $filteredData.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
        } 
        else {
             var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $filterType + ']');
             $filteredData.animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
        }

    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I need to get my new site launched and this bit of code is all that is holding me back!

Comment: Try to use `$fiteredData.fadeTo(500,1) and $filteredData.fadeTo(500,.5)` instead `animate`.

Comment: It still does nothing. Regardless of which way it's typed, everything is always at 100% opacity.

Comment: This is essentially the effect I'm looking for:

http://www.davewhitley.com

But everything doesn't have to start out black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Jj4FH/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="filterOptions">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-type="all">All</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-type="ty">Typography</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-type="pr">Print</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="ourHolder">
    <li class="ty"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
    <li class="il"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
    <li class="pr"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
    <li class="ty"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
    <li class="il"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
    <li class="pr"><a href="img.jpg"><img src="img.png"/></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');
    var $data = $holder.clone();
    var holders = $('.ourHolder li');
    $('#filterOptions li a').click(
    function (e) {
        // reset the active class on all the buttons
        $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
        // assign the class of the clicked filter option
        // element to our $filterType variable
        var $filterType = $(this).data('type');
        var noOpac = $(this).data('type');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if ($filterType == 'all') {
            // assign all li items to the $filteredData var when
            // the 'All' filter option is clicked
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
            $filteredData.animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 500);
            $('.ourHolder li').animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 0);
        } else {
            $('.ourHolder li').animate({
                opacity: 0.5
            }, 250);
            $.each(holders, function (i, v) {
                if ($(this).hasClass(noOpac)) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        opacity: 1.0
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I actually don't know what the .each portion does, but I appreciate the code so incredibly much.

Granted, this will work for what I need, but is there a way to get the fade in and fade out effect to happen simultaneously rather than one after the other?

Comment: The `$.each` is simply a jQuery iterator for the object that is holding the elements selected via `$('.ourHolder li')`. I ran through my jsFiddle several times and although the `<li>`'s are getting turned back on in succession, it's far too fast to individually distinguish them.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason when I use the demo, I get a bunch of pop up windows with true or false in them for each image, so I can't see how they transition. The way it shows on the website I'm working on, you can clearly see the fade out portion, then the fade in. It's okay when you switch between tabs, but on the first click from the all tab, where everything is at 100%, to any of the tabs, you clearly see it go from all 100%, to all 50%, to a few images back at 100%. It's not terrible, but if there is a way to fix it I would like to. If not, I'll just tweak it. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I left an 'alert' in there. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Jj4FH/1/

Oh, and please be sure to ACCEPT the answer if you're okay with it.

Comment: Must just be me noticing the pause more since my thumbnails are quite large. It's really not that big of a deal, it still does what I want it to. Thanks so much for all of your help! This puts my whole website launch back on track, and that's so fantastic.

Comment: I just adjusted the http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Jj4FH/ again.. try it now and see what you think.

Comment: Got it to do exactly what I want to do with a minor change, thank you again for all of your help!